# Client method not called in SignalR

Tags: c#-4.0, signalr

I am using signal R 1.0 with c#

the issue is most of the time with IE(v 10) and sometimes with chrome(v 28).

My client methods are not being executed.

I have chat functionality and on page load in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //here i call server method to create group between two users
});

chat.client.groupcreated = function(){} //this is not invoked
```

on server side i write Client.groupcreated()

It is working perfact in FF. More interesting thing is if i put a break point in my cs code at server side it works perfact in IE also

Comment: Try upgrading to SignalR 1.2 if you want to use .net 4.0 or 2.0+ if you're ok with using .net 4.5

Comment: I would also make sure you attach your client methods, e.g. "groupcreated" before you start your SignalR connection.

Comment: yes, all client methods have been attached before my connection starts

Answer (score 0):

Oppss...... I was doing a silly mistake

In the server method to create group i was doing something like below

```
Groups.Add(connectionid1,groupname);
Groups.Add(connectionid2,groupname);
Clients.Group(strGroupName).hellworld(); //no users added yet to the group while this line executes
```

The problem with above code is adding members to the signalr group is actually asynchronous, so sending messages to that group immediately won't work as the adding members to group may have not yet finished.

**Solution**

```
 Groups.Add(connectionid1, groupname).ContinueWith(t =>
                Groups.Add(connectionid2, groupname).ContinueWith(t2 => 
                    Clients.Group(groupname).helloworld());
```

wait for the task to complete before calling client method

By the way, thanks for posting your comments